# Save multiple images from Flash to server using JPGEncoder?

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3, encoding, file-upload

I'm trying to encode and upload two (or more) images from Flash using JPGEncoder. I can upload a single image with no problem, but have never needed to upload two or more encoded images. This is the code I'm using to encode and upload a single image.

```
var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(img.width,img.height,true,0);
bmd.draw(img);

var ba:ByteArray = new JPGEncoder(90).encode(bmd);

var vars:Object = new Object();
vars.path = 'uploads/';

var urlRequest : URLRequest = new URLRequest();
urlRequest.url = 'http://example.com/image.php';
urlRequest.contentType = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + UploadPostHelper.getBoundary();
urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
urlRequest.data = UploadPostHelper.getPostData('image.jpg',ba,vars);
urlRequest.requestHeaders.push(new URLRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache'));

var urlLoader : URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);
urlLoader.load(urlRequest);

function loadComplete(e:Event):void {
    trace(e.target.data);
}
```

Also, [here is the UploadPostHelper helper class](http://code.google.com/p/nascomaslib/source/browse/trunk/src/be/nascom/flash/net/upload/UploadPostHelper.as?r=21) that I'm using. Has anyone done this? Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you place all of your JPEG encoding and uploading into a function, you can call that function from `loadComplete(e:Event)`. An example name for the function could be `urlEncodeUpload()` Call the function once from your code and when it signals the `loadComplete`, it can call itself again (somewhat like an iterator, but using event driven style).

You'd need to check first whether you have any images left to encode and upload. If you have all of your images in an Array of their own, you could `pop()` the next bitmap until  it's empty, and pass that image to the `urlEncodeUpload()` function.

```
function urlEncodeUpload(img:*):void {
        var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(img.width,img.height,true,0);
        bmd.draw(img);

        var ba:ByteArray = new JPGEncoder(90).encode(bmd);

        var vars:Object = new Object();
        vars.path = 'uploads/';

        var urlRequest : URLRequest = new URLRequest();
        urlRequest.url = 'http://example.com/image.php';
        urlRequest.contentType = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + UploadPostHelper.getBoundary();
        urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        urlRequest.data = UploadPostHelper.getPostData('image.jpg',ba,vars);
        urlRequest.requestHeaders.push(new URLRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache'));

        var urlLoader : URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
        urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);
        urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
    }

function loadComplete(e:Event):void {
    if (imgArray.length > 0) urlEncodeUpload(imgArray.pop());
}
```

Hope that helps..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @AlexW. I was definitely over-complicating it.

Comment: Yep sometimes the answer is in the flow of control (design) and not an algorithm as such. Everyone has these issues, esp. with re-factoring etc.

Comment: Just an additional note - calling the upload function from the loadComplete function like this throws an error as this type of loader requires user interaction e.g. a button click. My solution was to us a loop in the urlEncodeUpload function.

Comment: Yeah that sounds like a better idea! :)

Comment: can you share the code showing how you solved the "loop in the urlEncodeUpload" issue? My app is uploading the first image no prob, but then hangs on any remaining images. thx corey